# Insert into multiple tables using Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

It's the first time I am using Room. I have a class called:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
class User{
   @PrimaryKey
   @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
   @SerializedName("id")
   String id;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
   @SerializedName("name")
   String name;

   @SerializedName("shift")
   @Ignore
   List<Shift> shifts; 
}

@Entity(tableName = "shifts")
class Shift{
   @PrimaryKey
   @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
   @SerializedName("id")
   String id;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time")
   @SerializedName("start_time")
   String startTime;

   @ColumnInfo(name = "end_time")
   @SerializedName("end_time")
   String endTime;
}
```

I want these two to be seperate tables in the database, hence I cannot user @Embedded annotation, as it will create a single table using all field as columns. I am using the above User class to store json reponse from the server as well, where I get the user and shift details information in a json object.

Is there any way I can insert the Shift details in **shifts** table as soon as I insert the User details in the **users** table ? I initially thought this will be handled using @Embeded but that will create **shift** table columns in the **user** table which I do not want.

Can someone help me as to how I am suppose to handle this in Room Persistence Library. Similar I will have to do for delete as well.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting User and Shift Data together in response ?

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid yes

Comment: Please post code for the response you are getting and Dao class for insertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can insert the Shift details in shifts table as soon as I insert the User details in the users table ?

Create your own DAO `@Transaction` method that calls inserts for `User` and `Shift`.

> Similar I will have to do for delete as well.

If you fix your `Shift` class, such that it has a `@ForeignKey` relationship to `User` with the appropriate cascade-delete option, deleting a `User` will delete its `Shift` rows as well. In your current implementation, `User` and `Shift` are unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, yes we updated the Shift class that has a Foreign key. It makes things more easier.