# Room Persistence Library transactions

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 entity classes:

```
@Entity(tableName = "work_orders")
public class WorkOrderEntity
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    ...
}

@Entity(tableName = "activity_logs", foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = WorkOrderEntity.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "work_order_id") })
public class ActivityLogEntity
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "work_order_id")
    private long workOrderId;
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to insert record in work_orders and activity_log tables in one transaction? Something like this:

```
@Transaction
public void insertBoth(WorkOrderEntity workOrderEntity, ActivityLogEntity activityLogEntity)
{
    insertWorkOrder(workOrderEntity);
    insertActivityLog(activityLogEntity);
}
```

with the foreign key constraint in mind.

Here is similar question [Insert into multiple tables using Room Persistence Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783228/insert-into-multiple-tables-using-room-persistence-library/46934222#46934222), but without elaborated answer

Comment: The `@Transaction` annotation exists, so your `insertBoth()` should be fine pretty much as written, assuming that `insertBoth()`, `insertWorkOrder()`, and `insertActivityLog()` are all methods on your `@Dao` class.

Comment: Yes, I put `insertBoth()`, `insertWorkOrder()` and `insertActivityLog()` in same `@Dao` class, but the problem is that after inserted WorkOrderEntity with autogenerated id, I need that id to set ActivityLogEntity `workOrderId`

Answer (score 2):

I come up with this solution:

```
@Transaction
public void insertBoth(WorkOrderEntity workOrderEntity, ActivityLogEntity activityLogEntity)
{
    long workOrderId = insertWorkOrder(workOrderEntity);
    activityLogEntity.setWorkOrderId(workOrderId);
    insertActivityLog(activityLogEntity);
}
```